# Can I do a LIST of all the objects on an S3 bucket with several million objects using MinIO?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, minio

We have an S3 bucket with tens of millions of objects in it.

I want to write a test that verifies that all of these files can be processed by my new code. From our rough calculation, it is likely to take several days.

Is it possible to run one `minioClient.ListObjectsV2()` command for that long?

Note that on how to [get the listing](https://docs.min.io/docs/golang-client-api-reference.html#ListObjectsV2) itself is documented in MinIO reference. I'm good with that.

Comment: S3 object lists are paginated.

Comment: AWS S3 won't allow you do that: "Returns some or all (up to 1,000) of the objects in a bucket" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html

Comment: @zerkms Isn't that what the `NextContinuationToken` feature is for? So that way it would send me the first 1,000, I work on those, then I get the next 1,000, etc. (although that part would be hidden in the MinIO code, not something I would myself have to do.)

Comment: @AlexisWilke my comment answers your only question asked: "Is it possible to run one LIST command for that long?". --- no, you cannot do that with one request/command.

Comment: @zerkms, ha! ha! my bad, I've updated the question, the point was about the MinIO listing capability rather than the plain `LIST` command from AWS S3.

Comment: What happens if new files are added while the tests are running ?

Comment: @marco.m That's something I'm also wondering about. It doesn't matter much in my case, but they are likely added "anywhere" in the list and thus will probably appear if after the current position or "be lost" if at a position we already checked. This would be similar to how the data is maintained in a database such as Cassandra.